# SQL and UTF-8 (SQL SCRIPT)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert special characters in a MySQL DB (5.6.17).
Not with a PHP script but in full SQL.

It's work with all characters "ù « » ê –" except for "à".

I need help, Thanks :)

DB Script :

```
create table movie (
mov_id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
mov_name varchar(100) not null,
mov_description_short varchar(500) not null,
mov_description_long varchar(2000) not null,
mov_author varchar(150) not null,
mov_year integer not null,
mov_poster varchar(150) not null) engine=innodb character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My SQL script :

```
INSERT INTO movie (mov_name, mov_description_short, mov_description_long,mov_author,mov_year,mov_poster) 
VALUES ('Hunger Games : La RÃ©volte, partie 2', 'Hunger Games : La RÃ©volte, partie 2 est un film amÃ©ricain de science-fiction dystopique rÃ©alisÃ© par Francis Lawrence, sorti en 2015.Il met en scÃ¨ne le personnage principal Katniss Everdeen interprÃ©tÃ© par Jennifer Lawrence et fait suite Ä Hunger Games (2012), L''Embrasement (2013) et Ä Hunger Games : La RÃ©volte, partie 1 (2014).', 'Alors que Panem est ravagÃ© par une guerre dÃ©sormais totale, Katniss et le PrÃ©sident Snow vont s''affronter pour la derniÃ¨re fois. Katniss et ses plus proches amis â€“ Gale, Finnick, et Peeta â€“ sont envoyÃ©s en mission pour le District 13 : ils vont risquer leur vie pour tenter d''assassiner le PrÃ©sident Snow, qui s''est jurÃ© de dÃ©truire Katniss. Les piÃ¨ges mortels, les ennemis et les choix dÃ©chirants qui attendent Katniss seront des Ã©preuves bien pires que tout ce qu''elle a dÃ©jÃ pu affronter dans l''arÃ¨ne...','Francis Lawrence',2015,'images/Hunger_Games_La_revolte_Partie_2.png');
```

The result on my PHP application :
[image]

Comment: What is the table definition ? Is it having char-set to utf-8 and also when you use PHP script does it set the charset to utf-8 while querying the DB ?

Comment: And when I insert a Movie with my PHP application (HTML form), it's work.
But it's for a school project, and we need to send a SQL Script to fill the DB.

Comment: Yes the table definition looks correct , now then you execute the query using PDO or mysqli you have an option to set the char-set http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php, and if you are using a form then the HTML meta for char-set should be set to utf-8 and finally `La RÃ©volte` is latin1 representation of uft8 you should be sending the data as utf8 as shown in the image.

Comment: Yes, I understand, when I add a movie with the HTML Form (so the PHP Script), it's ok.

The problem is that we can't send an empty DB to our teacher. That's why we have to send a SQL file ("content.sql").

Comment: Anyway, I found a solution : replace "à" with "Ã ".

Comment: `Ã©` is `é` interpreted as latin1 and converted to utf-8. So while you add the data you should add as `é` and it will be stored correctly, now while selecting the data if query is set to utf8 and your html meta is set correctly `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, but I think you didn't understand the question. I havn't problems with HTML or PHP, just with SQL script. The script will be executed directly in SQL, not in PHP ;)

Comment: Right so when you add them directly into sql you should be using original utf8 `é` not `Ã©`

Comment: When I use (in sql)  "é,à,ù,..." it didn't work...
That's why I use "Ã©"

Comment: Also, when I add a movie with the HTML form, it's stored in DB with "Ã©,..." not with "é,à,ù,..."

Comment: Meaning your html page is not set correct content type check the source on browser.

Comment: HTML code -> http://piratepad.net/avcs

Comment: Check the head of the HTML but I think it's well set...
No?

Comment: Yes i just checked and looks good, now bit confused on the issue, ideally if all the parameters are set to utf-8 it should work properly, even when you add them directly into the DB

Answer (score 2):

Two things are required to store UTF-8 data from an SQL file :

1. Your SQL file has to use the UTF-8 character encoding. I think you
   are using latin1 (ISO8859-1 or ISO8859-15) for now. Check your text
   editor options for that.
2. Your connection to the DB must use the UTF-8 character encoding. For
   that you have to execute the following SQL query before any other
   query :

   SET NAMES utf8;

The actual database storage should be UTF-8, but since you are only storing french characters it could be latin1 too.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should use `nvarchar` in table creation.

2- you should use `N` before your text in `insert`. For instance:

`VALUES (N'Hunger Games : La RÃ©volte')`